# Alert when a wifi network is detected

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, notification-area

Is there any way to play a sound and give a notification in Windows (7 or 8) to alert me when a wifi (wireless) network is detected ?Can I do it with the task scheduler?
I can do that in Ubuntu using a [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345886/alert-when-a-wifi-network-is-detected). Can I do that in windows?

Comment: which os xp or 7?why not configure sounds at notification area?

Comment: windows7 and win8

Comment: Yes you can. See [http://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection](http://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection). In your case the command would be something which just displays a popup stating that a network is found or even a command which only triggers on a specific network.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [Snarl](http://fullphat.net/?page_id=50) and Growl (for [Mac](http://growl.info) and Windows, the latter of which you'll have to Google since I can only post two links) to be of interest.  They're both notification programs; each has plugins that allow them to monitor various aspects of the system as well as APIs that allow other programs to interface with them (generally via other plugins) in order to send their own notifications.

...I unfortunately misunderstood your question initially.  I thought you were looking for a notification of network *connections*, not of network *detections*.  I know Snarl has an included plugin for the former (Growl may or may not have one as well).  Regardless, you may be able to find a plugin for one of the two that does what you want (or if you know how to code, you may be able to make one yourself by modifying an existing plugin).