# Syncing files automatically on usb insert

Tags: usb, sync

So basically I have an encrypted usb stick that I use as my "main" storage to all my files and stuff.  But I also work on numerous machines including my home computer so every now and then I make files to different locations than the usb.  Of course I also make backups of the said usb to my home computer.

Basically what I would like is to find a piece of software that syncs predefined locations from my home computer with my usb stick whenever I stick it in so I wouldn't have to do that manually.  Does something like that exists?  I know there are syncing data but are there any with that specific functionality?

Oh and I would welcome an answer that takes into account both Linux and Windows systems :)

Comment: For linux see this: [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in).  For windows look at this post [http://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection](http://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection) (ignore the network part, focus on the event part).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I achieve this:

- I have [Librekey](http://www.liberkey.com/en.html) set up on my usb
  drive.
  <sub>I prefer it for this as opposed to [Portable
  Apps](http://portableapps.com/) because of it's file association
  utility.</sub>
- The usb automatically fires up librekey when it is inserted and starts Dsynchronize which i have set up to run the sync when launched.
  <sub>Free File Sync can also be installed easily on a librekey which would also work and it includes a real time sync feature.</sub>

That's pretty much that. It does not care whether the system is linux or windows. Probably works osx too but I have no idea