# How to schedule a task on secondary audio/video device connection/disconnection?

Tags: windows, hdmi, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a windows task to run when a secondary output device (e.g., VGA monitor or HDMI A/V receiver is turned on or off) but I'm not sure which event should be used for this. I found something related to network cable plug/unplug here [How to launch a command on network connection/disconnection?](https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection) , but nothing for external audio/video devices. Any such event or events exist? If not, any other way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following on from your link above, I found that I could get this working for audio devices using the following event data:

```
Log:       Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager/Admin
Source:    DeviceSetupManager
Event ID:  112
```

ID 112 seems to process newly connected devices.  In Windows logs I had the following:

> Device 'LG-BDHT' ({db41aaf1-ce7e-5de5-904e-9b6d7560d7ba}) has been
>   serviced, processed 4 tasks, wrote 0 properties, active worktime was
>   427 milliseconds.

This event seems to occur when I turn on my Bluray player (which then allows pass through access to my TV as a monitor).

Hope this could help you get things working!  Worst case scenario, look through you event logs for something that happens around the time that your TV turns on.

Comment: I know this is old, but in case it helps any others that don't plan to check the event viewer for their details, I didn't see anything in `Log:       Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager/Admin`. The two displays I plugged into my HDMI port gave me results from the "System" log (`Event Viewer > Windows Logs > System`). The corresponding values above would be `Source: Display` and an `Event ID: 4107` in my case. Note: They both appear when connecting and disconnecting the monitors.