# Auto-remap Windows shares?

Tags: windows, backup

I backup teacher laptops to a Windows server share.  Unfortunately, when they go home still logged in and come back the next day, the share isn't automatically remapped, so backups fail.  Is there any way to make shares automatically remap when they are in range of our wireless net?  Thanks.  If not, I guess we need to pay for something like CrashPlan (which I love, but we're on a limited budget).

Answer (score 1):

Non-technical suggestion:

Tell them to logoff before leaving the building and/or rebooting once when the come back, put it in the IT/computer usage policy for the organization, and make them sign it.  If they can't do that, remove their right to take the computer home (since you can't trust them to follow basic rules of use).

Technical suggestion:

Don't use mapped drives. Instead use an [UNC path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) to reference the target share (ie: `\\server\sharedfolder`).

Alternatively, if you're determined to have it remap the on connection, then write a script to map the drive(s), and setup a task as explained in this SU question:

[How to launch a command on network connection/disconnection?](https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection)

Answer (score 0):

Open your notepad and type the below content

```
net use x: \\computer\share /persistent:yes
```

save the file as **automap.bat**

Go to start and type "task scheduler" and open Task scheduler

Go to create task -> Triggers(New) -> select Begin the task as **On an event** and select the below parameters

**Log**: Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational

**Source**: NetworkProfile

**Event ID**: 10000

Once it is done go to **"Actions"** tab and browser your automap.bat file

You can set the time interval as you wish.

This will connect your network share when network connection is active.

Comment: You need to have double slashes `\\computer`