# How to use hamachi IP when connecting remotely, and local IP when connected locally

Tags: vpn, windows-10, hamachi

Using hamachi and windows 10, but may be relevant to other VPNs to

I access a server either locally on the lan, or remotely over hamachi VPN

Is there a method to make the switch seamless?
something like a virtual IP address that can be failed over between these IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tee solution I found:

- set up rules to run when connecting to the local or remote networks 
  based on: https://superuser.com/a/262880/68818
- the rules trigger a script that overwrites etc\hosts with a file that is suitable for the relevant enviroment