# Automatically mute Windows volume when I'm at work?

Tags: windows-10, script

On my Android phone, I have a little script that fires whenever it connects to a new Wi-Fi hotspot, that I have set up to set everything to mute when it sees the Wi-Fi at work.

I'd like my work Windows laptop to mute itself when I'm at work too. I see some mentions of using Visual Basic scripting to do this on Windows but it looks pretty arcane. Is there a similar lightweight way to do this in Windows 10?

Comment: You'll need to use some sort of application to monitor your network (either by IP address or when a specific SSID is connected to) and run a script when it's connected. There are various automated proxy configruation applications available that change IE proxy settings based on certain criteria. Some allow custom scripts to be run when certain network criteria are met...

Answer (score 2):

You may use the Task Scheduler to launch a script upon connecting to your work
network.

The script can use, for example, the free tool
[nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
to mute Windows volume as follows:

```
nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1
```

For creating the scheduled task, see the post
[How to launch a command on network connection/disconnection](https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection).

You may examine in Event Viewer the attributes of the event described in the post,
to find the condition that names the network connection name which you may use
in the trigger condition for the task.