# Connect automatically to wifi as soon as available and if it gets disconnected connect again

Tags: windows-10, batch, windows-task-scheduler, vbscript, event-viewer

My windows 10 disconnects automatically from wifi sometime. My pc is not having monitor i am controlling it over remote desktop team viewer.
Also sometimes running cleanup utilities disable the auto reconnect settings from wifi.

At startup and during runtime

What i want is to keep scanning wifi if desired access point available then connect to it and keep scanning it if it gets disconnected then reconnect

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Task Scheduler to schedule periodically the reconnection
every few minutes by using the command:

```
netsh wlan connect name=WIFI_SSID
```

You could base a batch script to schedule on
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35996777/165358):

```
:loop
  netsh interface show interface | find "WIFI_SSID" /I /C
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 goto :connected
  netsh wlan connect name=WIFI_SSID
  timeout 5 >nul
goto :loop
:connected
```

For more control (if required) see also
[How to launch a command on network connection/disconnection?](https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection)